Swift LZMA decompress String
I am trying to compress and decompress a String using lzma.
Decompress process goes without any errors, after that if I take compressed data and try to decompress it back, as it is, all good.
But I need to save compressed date to file, so when app is running I can get string and decompress it at runtime, this is where problems begins. I get exactly string, that I got from compressed process before, but at decompress I got error that says

Decompression error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=5377 "(null)

My compress process:
var dataForCompress = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
let data = dataForCompress.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData
let compressedData = try data.compressed(using: .lzma)

After that I tried to decompress string by convert compressedData to string and decompress this string like that:
var dataString = String(decoding: compressedData, as: UTF8.self)
let nsdata = dataString.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData
let uncompressedData = try nsdata.decompressed(using: .lzma) as Data
let theString = String(data: uncompressedData, encoding: .utf8)

At that point I got the error.
If I just do this:
let uncompressedData = try compressedData.decompressed(using: .lzma) as Data

Uncompress compressed date straight forward, its decompressed without error.
I think problem is somewhere at my process with get data from string, because size of the string I get when convert data to string is much more than size of compressed data itself.

var dataString = String(decoding: compressedData, as: UTF8.self) Not all Data can be converted into UTF8 String. I don't know about lzma, but there could be invalid UTF8 sequences. Why do you need to do that instead of directly convert?

I need to get compressed data from Remote Config, unfortunately I can receive inly string from Remote Config, and as I see it now, its impossible to store and later receive correct compressed date as string
